# Force users to authenticate

Tags: networking

I have set up an Ubuntu server as a firewall/gateway router following the article here:
https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/ubuntu-as-a-firewallgateway-router/

Everything seems to work fine, but I would like the Windows clients to have to enter a username and password in order to gain access to the internet.

Can/how could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is called captive portal. Google it. If then do you have any doubts, update your post.

Comment: @Helio: That's correct.  However, [lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Helio) is not allowed as a comment or an answer here...  Better to not say anything then that...  [Have a look here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=lmgtfy) for the discussions on this topic...  ;-)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't said it with bad intention, only seemed so obvious and I thought: `If he finds a good tutorial on Internet and, if sucess, post here his experience, may be better than make a looong response with thousands of steps :-)` However if do you find it offensive, I'll remove it.

Comment: @hello; Thanks for the fast response!  I did google it and I found using Pfsense seemed a better fit for me since it is a router / firewall with a captive portal system built in.  Seeded to be an easier solution rather than the Ubuntu install and adding and configuring many seperate packages